# Boto3 doesn't use keys from config file

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, boto3

I want Boto3 to get the access and secret key from a config file instead of hard coding them. On my Linux server I set the following environment variable `AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE` with the value `/app/.aws/credentials`. In /app/.aws/ I put a file with the name credentials with the following content:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = abcd
aws_secret_access_key = abcd
```

Of course I used the actual keys instead of abcd.

Python:

```
import boto3
conn = boto3.client('s3',
                    region_name="eu-west-1",
                    endpoint_url="endpoint",
                    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
                    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
                    config=Config(signature_version="s3", s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}))
```

However it says `name'aws_access_key_id' is not defined`. How can I fix it? Thanks

Edit:

```
>>> os.environ['AWS_SHARED_CREDENTIALS_FILE']
'/app/.aws/credentials'
```

Comment: Don't store long-lived credentials on servers if you can avoid it. Use an IAM role to grant permissions via temporary credentials (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I use an S3 service that is not hosted by Amazon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have credentials folder with aws credentials already created, this means you don't need to specify them when instantiating your client. The following should work:

```
import boto3

conn = boto3.client('s3',
                region_name="eu-west-1",
                endpoint_url="endpoint",
                config=Config(signature_version="s3", s3={'addressing_style': 'path'}))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are running your application on an EC2 instance, you can also assign a S3 role to your instance and have boto assume that role. Prevents you from having to store keys in your instance.

Look at the section "Assume Role Provider" in the docs:

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html

Link to IAM roles as well:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html